# City grid problem: how to interpret such that we use Vandermonde's convolution

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A person wants to return to their house that is two blocks north and three blocks east. The problem resolves to taking five moves such that two are northward; there are thus $C(5,2) = 10$ total paths.

But that's not the problem I want to do; I want to illustrate that we can build this grid out of combinations of the northward moves and combinations of the eastward moves (*i.e.* use Vandermonde's convolution to build it.)

As a matter of fact, we can write

$$ C(5,2) = \sum_{j = 0}^2 C(2,j)C(3,2-j) = 3 + 6 + 1.$$

These numbers do seem to invoke a correspondence in the problem. If your second move is your first right, we get: DRRRD, DRRDR, DRDRR, corresponding to $C(2,0)C(3,2) = 3$.

If your first move is your first right, we get: RRRDD, RRDRD, RRDDR, RDRDR, RDRRD, RDDRR, corresponding to $C(2,1)C(3,1) = 6$.

And if you do both your downs first, you only get DDRRR, corresponding to $C(2,2)C(3,0) = 1$.

This is a combinatorics talks for a general audience that introduces generating functions in a concrete, accessible way. I'm trying to get to Vandermonde's identity without doing any abstract combinatorial proofs, and I'm just missing the interpretation I should make here.

Comment: The geometrical proof on this page might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!